# unexpected % symbol after running cpp program in vscode terminal

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, clang++

[image]

tried running code but I'm facing  an unexpected "%" symbol at end of the output.

```
#include < iostream >
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << " abc " ;
}
```

please help!!!

Comment: That's probably just a marker your IDE/shell adds to let you know that there's no newline

Comment: I'm guessing that's just the O/S prompt. Try `cout << " abc \n";` instead.

Answer (score 2):

That is most likely your shell telling you that the output did not place a newline. zsh and fish do this by default, I believe. The screenshot indicates macOS, which does use zsh as of Catalina.

If you don't want to see that, change your code to output a newline.
`cout << " abc \n";`